# Delete a table row in SQL using PHP using date parameters

Tags: php, sql, delete-row

How can I delete a table row in using PHP and SQL?

For example when a scheduled event has passed the scheduled date, it is automatically deleted from the table, like an expiration date so to speak. I am currently making a reservation system for scheduled events.

Comment: Quite some more detail needed; could you show the schema of the table? Are you storing times as local time or UTC? When should scheduled events be removed? Immediately? After a week?

Comment: You might also want to think about why you're deleting the row. If you don't have a specific reason for deleting it you might be better off keeping it there.

Comment: Storing the schedules as local time, and I'm planning to remove them from the table when the scheduled date has passed. For example the scheduled date of the table entry is today, the next day it will be removed from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy a cron job which runs regularly (like once in 15 minutes) and make it delete the rows that are older than a specific date and time.

There is no expiration feature in SQL.

Comment: yeap, cronjob here would be easiest solution. Of course if you don't need entries to be deleted in real-time. So keep the period you've set in cronjob in mind and validate the expiration date when showing events (just to avid showing the ones which are over but still waiting for cronjob to delete them).

Answer (score 1):

A cron job can be a solution but I rather use a jobs/events on databases for tasks running on databases.
Create a stored procedure which will delete desired rows triggered by database job/event.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know there is an event scheduler built into databases. Thanks for a great hint!